# Test management product recommendation

Tags: test-management

I am looking for a test management product to structure our current manual testing. What I would like to it handle is:

- recording of test cases, including parametrised ones;
- historical analysis of trends: number of tests, duration, succes criteria;
- ability to "feed" test results, e.g. from automatic acceptance tests with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/);
- ability to open tasks in an issue tracker based on failed testing runs.

The price tag is obviously important, so free products are preferred. As we are a software company, an architecture which allows us to develop plugins is appreciated.

Comment: Product recommendations are a pretty big no-no on SO sites. This should be closed

Comment: @Bruce: [citation needed] . Any meta question threads which can clarify this?

Comment: Have a look at http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1089/superuser-com-getting-useless-for-me ... the Super user FAQs point it out ... "It's not about ... a shopping or buying recommendation". This question has the potential to be open ended and argumentative.

Comment: @Bruce SuperUser is a very different animal than most SE sites. It's aimed at enthusiasts, not professionals. Someone who evaluates a product in a professional capacity will be able to provide a much more objective view on it, making that assessment more "SO friendly."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Klaros Test management](http://www.klaros-testmanagement.com/home) seems to fit my requirements nicely. It comes with a Free community edition which supports (partial list) :

- Management of Test Related Artifacts
- Grouping Test Cases to Test Suites
- Version Control of Test Cases and Test Suites
- Statistics
- Guided manual test execution
- Interoperability with Continuous Integration Systems (Hudson)
- Interoperability with Issue Tracking Systems

Here's how a run report template looks ( [full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S9LD.png) ) :

[image: Run report template]

There's of course an Entreprise Edition as well with bells and whistles.

Answer (score 7):

Your asked for a test management product to structure our current manual testing, in this case, you can try out [Test Link](http://testlink.org), which is an open source tool. It has almost everything you need to organize your manual testings including: test plans, test cases, test results, and test reports. Check out the tool for more details.

Then you asked the integration of Selenium for your automation feature, you may also look at the [xStudio](http://www.xqual.com/). It's free to download and use, and you can also purchase for commercial supports. It has rich features for selenium integration (htmlsuite, Java, C#, Ruby, python). Take a look at the overview of its documentation here: [link to docs](http://www.xqual.com/documentation/documents.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

That would be one nifty product. I cannot speak from personal experience but I can point you to few low cost alternatives as per Randy Rice's recent blog ([link to article](http://randallrice.blogspot.com/2011/05/stareast-2011-free-and-cheap-test-tools.html?spref=tw)):

**Testrail** and **Runtestrun** look like possible options for you

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest [TestLodge - Test Case Management Tool](http://www.testlodge.com). This is a tool that I have and continue to develop.

It can handle your requirements in the following ways:

- recording of test cases - All test cases are grouped into test suites as a way of keeping them organized. This is what you would create your test runs from.
- historical analysis of trends - All activity to recorded to an audits table and this data is then displayed via a range of graphs and an activity dashboard for each project.
- ability to "feed" test result - This isn't something that we currently support, but it is on our list of things to investigate once all the more popular feature requests are complete.
- ability to open tasks in an issue tracker - We integrate with 4 issue trackers and offer the ability to automatically submit tickets when you mark a test as failed.

As for the price, there is a free plan, but this is a commercial tool and paid plans start from a low monthly fee.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question and you have already found a solution, but for others looking at this post I'll put my two pennies worth in and suggest [Enterprise Tester](http://catchsoftware.com/software/enterprise-tester). It meets all of the requirements listed (see notes below) and has an API, so would allow plugins to be developed.

- Recording of test cases, including parametrised ones - Enterprise Tester allows you to record test cases and then execute those tests across one or many execution sets.
- Historical analysis of trends: number of tests, duration, success criteria - We have developed a testing query language (TQL) which allows you to analyse and report on tests (including building dashboards) within and across projects.
- Ability to "feed" test results, e.g. from automatic acceptance tests
  with Selenium - Enterprise Tester can capture results from Selenium and a few other automated tools, including anything that outputs to NUnit and JUnit.
- Ability to open tasks in an issue tracker based on failed testing run - Integrates with JIRA and TFS for defect tracking.

Enterprise Tester isn't a free test management tool, but starts at $1,200 for the smallest license, so not a huge cost when price is a factor.

I hope that helps others reading this stream.

Cheers Stacy

**Disclosure:** I work for [Catch Software](http://catchsoftware.com/), the company that develops Enterprise Tester.